# Is there such a field as applied $\infty$-category theory?

Tags: ct.category-theory, soft-question, infinity-categories, applications

It seems that applied category theory has exploded in popularity in recent years.

My question is simple: had there been any work using $\infty$-category theory in applications?

Edit: By applications, I mean specifically outside pure mathematics, more on less in the same way category theory can be applied to computer science and network theory.

Comment: One application which loosely comes to mind: encode infinite data sets in higher coherent modal structures which are then represented by finite data types in the form of monoidal $\infty$-categories.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of $\infty$-category theory that it is to be applied to homotopical questions?

Comment: What does “applied” mean to you?  There’s plenty of applications to other fields of math, I’ve applied results about $(\infty,n)$-categories to tensor categories.  Or does it have to be applied outside of math?  Are applications to theoretical computer science kosher, or does the “theoretical” in TCS mean that’s not applied?

Comment: "Univalent foundations" of Voevodsky is heavily relied on the $\infty$-category stuff and has applications in dependend type theory.

Comment: None that I personally know of (which do not mean that much). But maybe one should say something obvious: $\infty$-category theory exists as a field for maybe 10 or 15 years (the idea of higher category is a lot older, but the systematic study of weak $\infty$-categories is quite recent, 20 years to be large). Ordinary category theory is closer to be 60 or even 70 years old, and the idea of having application of category theory outside of pure math is also fairly recent... So maybe one just need to wait a couple of decades to also find application of higher categories outside of mathematics ?

Comment: @SimonHenry Applications of category theory to computer science date back to the 70s: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-07142-3 (Maybe this is "fairly recent" in terms of the entire history of mathematics.)